# Log mongo queries client side (c# driver)

Tags: .net, mongodb, logging

I'm using the official c# driver for mongo. I would really like to log queries **on the client side**. Especially, I would like to see how `Linq` queries are translated into mongo queries before they are sent to the server.

I know I can turn on profiling on the sever, but I want it client side.

Is there any hooks that can be used in the mongo driver? It seems really closed... No interfaces, no events... But I hope I have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.x does not have any hooks like you are wanting. Our next version, 2.0, will most certainly have these hooks built-in.

Comment: any schedule and roadmap for version 2. anywhere?

Comment: These are the tickets left for 2.0. Sometimes more get added, and sometimes we pull them out. A beta should be coming out soon. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP/fixforversion/11181

Comment: Nice! I see a couple of other things there that I looking forward to, so keep up the good work :-)

Comment: Any news for the 2.2 version of the C# driver? I can't find anything working. Is the ClusterBuilder and the Subscribe method the right way to go?

Comment: Yes, ClusterBuilder and Subscribe is the way to go.